# use value and label in php dropdown

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have this code to pull values and labels from a MySQL DB and populate a drop down box, on change it put the value in a text field, but I want the label not the value.

Any pointers would be good..

```
<select name="CompanyInternalID" autofocus class="textBox" id="CompanyInternalID" style="width:300px" onchange="document.form1.CompName.value=this.value">
                      <?php
do {  
?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row_rsCustomerList['AKA']?>"><?php echo $row_rsCustomerList['CustomerName']?></option>
                      <?php
} while ($row_rsCustomerList = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomerList));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsCustomerList);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rsCustomerList, 0);
      $row_rsCustomerList = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomerList);
  }
?>
                </select>
                  <input type="text" name="CompName" class="textBox" style="width:180px" id="CompName" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to get the selected value and put in the required text field.

Suppose the id of dropdown is "drop" and id of text field is "txt_id" . Now you can use below code:

```
$("#drop").change(function () { 
     $("#txt_id").val($(this).val());
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, not used jQuery, can you give me a hint as to where it goes etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:
You can also learn jQuery at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

```
    <!doctype html>

   <html>

<head>

<title>My Page</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<select name="CompanyInternalID" autofocus class="textBox" id="CompanyInternalID" style="width:300px" > <?php do { ?> <option value="<?php echo $row_rsCustomerList['AKA']?>"><?php echo $row_rsCustomerList['CustomerName']?></option> <?php } while ($row_rsCustomerList = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomerList)); $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsCustomerList); if($rows > 0) { mysql_data_seek($rsCustomerList, 0); $row_rsCustomerList = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomerList); } ?> </select> <input type="text" name="CompName" class="textBox" style="width:180px" id="CompName" />

<script>
$("#CompanyInternalID").change(function () { $("#CompName").val($(this).val());
 }
);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```